# Using Select HTML in Bootstrap Popovers

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I want to be be able to utilize a select few HTML tags in a Bootstrap popover.  I know that I could include the option HTML = true in the settings, but this would leave me exposed to an XSS attack (wouldn't it?).

I am looking to allow a select few tags - just like when I use wp_kses with the $allowedposttags global.

(p.s. I'm asking this here instead of stackoverflow because I'm wondering whether some built-in WordPress functionality may be the ticket).

Comment: If you know how [`wp_kses()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_kses/) works and it fits your needs - just use it? Just pass own list of allowed stuff.

Comment: but how would I use it in this instance?

Comment: There aren't enough details in your question to understand what "this instance" means. :) Please elaborate.